# Statistics and probability - the basics

Tags: probability, statistics

With $x$ assuming random values if $1$, $2$, or $4$ and if you know the expected value of $x$ is equal to $2.7$. If you are only given  one other piece of information $P(X=1) = 0.3$ then how can you find $p(x=2)$ and $p(x=4)$?  I tried working backwards knowing the $e(x)$ but don’t think I have enough information. Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  let $p(x=2)=a$.  Can you then compute $p(x=4)$ in terms of $a$?   Then use the expectation to compute $a$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You have a system of three equations with three unknowns:
$$\mathbb E[X]=P(X=1)+2P(X=2)+4P(X=4)=2.7$$
$$P(X=1)=0.3$$
$$P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=4)=1$$
The third equation is probably the only one that you were missing.

Comment: And I would just solve this algeabraically?

Comment: @user605811 Yup, that's it! Do you understand why the third equation is true? If you have any questions or there  is any part that you don't grasp, please feel free to ask.